# rails: nested form with 2 foreign keys in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model "Post" which belongs_to "Group."  The url is like this .../groups/26/posts/1 everything was working fine until I needed to add a user name to each post so I added a new foreign key to the Posts table for "User" and made the Post model belongs_to :user, and in the User model added has_many :posts.

My issue is that I don't know how to create a new post so that I can get both the group_id and user_id added to the posts table.

This works to populate the `user_id` foreign key of the Posts table.  I need to call group in here somehow but can't make it work.

```
def new
  @posts = current_user.posts.build  
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)    

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created successfully!"
    redirect_to group_url(@post.group)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This works to populate the `group_id` foreign key of the Posts table, I would need to call @user or current_user in here somehow but not sure how to do it.

```
# GET /groups/:group_id/posts/new
def new
  @posts = @group.posts.new 
end

def create
  @post = @group.posts.new(post_params)   

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created successfully!"
    redirect_to group_url(@post.group)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the user manually to both the `new` and `create` actions, like this:

```
# GET /groups/:group_id/posts/new
def new
  @post = @group.posts.new(user_id: current_user.id)
end

def create
  @post = @group.posts.new(post_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))   

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created successfully!"
    redirect_to group_url(@post.group)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting the `@group`/`current_user` when you do the build/new of the `@post`.

here is an example of how to add the group:

```
def new
  @posts = current_user.posts.build(group: @group)
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)  
  @post.group = @group  

  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created successfully!"
    redirect_to group_url(@post.group)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

@moveson posted the other way, of adding the `current_user` to the `@post` created with from the `@group`
(he posted while i wrote my answer :D )

**EDIT 2:**

Actually, i would go with the other way. (setting the `current_user` like the other answer)

BUT! do you really need to set the current user on the `new` method?

You can show the `current_user` info on the html page anyway, and then set it only in the `create` method! (when you actually going to save it to the DB....)

Comment: that's true, I probably only need it in the create action.  thank you for your answer it helped me understand both ways of accomplishing this.  much appreciated.

Comment: It is probably not necessary to add the user_id in the `new` action, but it can't hurt, and it may come in handy once you get to the form view.

Comment: @moveson if he uses `devise` - he can use `current_user` anyway in the views! :D but that way he can use `@post.user` if he needs it!  @scott You are welcome

Comment: Yep, he certainly could. But I think it's more obvious and straightforward to just add the user when you make the object.

Comment: @moveson - yes and no. the `new` action doesn't creates the object in the db, it just send it to the view so you could use that data. When the user submits the form for creation, that data is sent back to the `create` method which is AGAIN creating an object, but that time saves it to the db. the `user_id` will be sent back to the create method from the form -> which is **DANGEROUS**! because users can edit (even hidden) form fields, so that data can be manipulated. @Scott should (and MUST in my opinion) use the `current_user` for safety on the server side.

Comment: The user_id could be maniupulated whether or not it is included in the `new` action. And if the user_id is manipulated in the form and sent back via params, whether it was included in the non-persisted object or not, it will not matter, because it will be merged out and replaced with the correct current_user.id. Take a closer look at the first line of the `create` action in my answer.

Comment: yup, and thats why he doesn't really need to populate the `user` in the `new` method, its unnecessary, but lets let him decide what is best for him haha :)

Comment: I already agreed it was not necessary--just possibly useful, and if useful, then the best place to do it is in the `new` action, in my opinion.